# "URL workspaceid parameter is not a valid GUID." after deploying car dashboard on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

I entered the Workspace ID for the conversation service as described [car dashboard app](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/car-dashboard). However, it was deleted somehow during the re-deployment of the app, leading to an error when running it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downloaded cloned the repository, created the service, set the environment variable, and pushed to Bluemix.

The sample worked correctly.

Then I performed another `cf push` on my local machine, and the application redeployed from my local machine back to Bluemix.

The sample worked correctly again, and the environment variable was not deleted.

I would suggest putting in your `WORKSPACE_ID` environment variable in again and making sure you don't delete your application when you redeploy.

Comment: I was deploying it directly to BM. Maybe it was because of restaging.

Comment: yes, at less for now. There are some instabilities that might be caused by the app, which does not appear to be final. thx